# How do I know if my server / server application can multi-cast videos?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-server-2008

May I know how do I know if my server (e.g. Ubuntu Server, Windows Server 2008, etc...) / server application (e.g. IIS, GlassFish, etc...) can multi-cast videos (or do multi-cast streaming of videos)